# How to properly add include directories with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

About a year ago I asked about [header dependencies in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461000/handling-header-files-dependencies-with-cmake).

I realized recently that the issue seemed to be that CMake considered those header files to be *external* to the project. At least, when generating a Code::Blocks project the header files do not appear within the project (the source files do). It therefore seems to me that CMake consider those headers to be *external* to the project, and does not track them in the depends.

A quick search in the CMake tutorial only pointed to `include_directories` which does not seem to do what I wish...

What is the proper way to signal to CMake that a particular directory contains headers to be included, and that those headers should be tracked by the generated Makefile?

Answer (score 427, accepted):

Two things must be done.

First add the directory to be included:

```
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${YOUR_DIRECTORY})
```

In case you are stuck with a very old CMake version (2.8.10 or older) without support for `target_include_directories`, you can also use the legacy `include_directories` instead:

```
include_directories(${YOUR_DIRECTORY})
```

Then you also must add the header files to the list of your source files for the current target, for instance:

```
set(SOURCES file.cpp file2.cpp ${YOUR_DIRECTORY}/file1.h ${YOUR_DIRECTORY}/file2.h)
add_executable(test ${SOURCES})
```

This way, the header files will appear as dependencies in the Makefile, and also for example in the generated Visual Studio project, if you generate one.

How to use those header files for several targets:

```
set(HEADER_FILES ${YOUR_DIRECTORY}/file1.h ${YOUR_DIRECTORY}/file2.h)

add_library(mylib libsrc.cpp ${HEADER_FILES})
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${YOUR_DIRECTORY})
add_executable(myexec execfile.cpp ${HEADER_FILES})
target_include_directories(myexec PRIVATE ${YOUR_DIRECTORY})
```

Comment: Ah! I knew it must be something stupid. Indeed, I did not listed the headers... Do I need to list the headers of just this library, or also all the headers that it might depend on (on top of declaring the dependency on the library) ? It's a growing project and I quite dread the idea of adding a header to *all* the dependencies when I add one in the root library.

Comment: To allow for better dependency tracking (for example to make sure modifying a header file triggers compilation for all affected targets), yes. However you can use cmake variables to list the header files only once and use them in several places, see my edit.

Comment: My question was more in the sense that I have several libraries which depend from each other: libroot, liba depends on libroot, libb depends on libroot. Can I use the `LIBROOT_HEADER_FILES` variable in `liba/CMakefile` and `libb/CMakefile` then ?

Comment: If you have several CMakeLists.txt files, you can SET your variable in the libroot subdirectory using the PARENT_SCOPE option, which will make the variable known in the parent CmakeLists.txt file, therefore available for the other subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to completely cover my needs, I'll need to test it out (obviously) but so far it looks great :)

Comment: Instead of putting the `${HEADER_FILE}` inside both the `add_library()`and the `add_executable()` macros, is it also possible to put them in a `include_directories()` immediately after `set()`, and leave them out in the last 2 macros?

Comment: @rhalbersma the add_* commands are not macros, and include_directories() is not used to list header files, but **directories** containing header files in order for the compiler to find them, therefore, the answer is no. This command does not magically add file dependency tracking.

Comment: @SirDarius OK, thanks. I am trying to get a test-suite of a header-only template library to work, and I got confused between the headers of the test-suite and those of the library itself, might ask a question about it later if I can't figure it out.

Comment: This is wrong, you should _never_ use `include_directories` over `target_include_directories`. The former sets it recursively for all targets in that directory; whereas the latter sets it for a target. Doing the former breaks the notion of a target graph in CMake, and instead relies on side effects to your file hierarchy.

Comment: Is there any way to include whole directory without adding each file one-by-one? The directory that I want to include contains nearly 100 header files.

Comment: Why do you have to explicitly list the `.h` files in your executable's source files? Surely you should just specify the path to your headers then use `#include <filename.h>` from your implementation `.cpp` files?

Comment: @donturner You don't have to add `.h` files into `add_executable`.  But, It does have the nice benefit of making the files show up in `Visual Studio` projects in the expected location. `Makefiles` uses the internal `cmake -E cmake_depends` to generate dependencies from the source files (header files in `add_executable` are skipped).  There are known [issues](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16277) with this the scanner.  Also ` CMake's Makefile generator dependency scanner does only approximate preprocessing.` Computed header includes and that sort of thing will not work.

Comment: But how do you figure out the directory? Say I'm trying to find D:/TeamCity/mod/thirdparty/vcpkg-msvc_15.9.21-2d63525/installed/x64-windows-custom/include/aws/core/Aws.h>  and msvc cannot find #include<aws/core/Aws.h> and the 'vcpkg-msvc_15.9.21-2d63525' portion of the path isn't constant? I see things like ${_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR} and ${THIRDPARTY_LIB_DIR} but I can't figure out what permutation of things I need to get a working path targeted. Especially when the above dir and the src are in two completely different places.

Comment: Many times I've tried to find this answer but could only find answers to similar questions and which recommend using GLOB and I eventually give up looking. Would be super handy if this answer was included/linked on the other questions or they were phrased better to be distinctly dissimilar.

Comment: I think modern Cmake should introduce the header file through target_include_directories (using PUBLIC PRIVATE INTERFACE to control propagation) instead of specifying it in add_library or add_executable

Comment: While this post answers the "how" part of the question, it doesn't realy go into the "why" part at all. which I think is a missed opportunity.

Answer (score 110):

First, you use `include_directories()` to tell CMake to add the directory as `-I` to the compilation command line. Second, you list the headers in your `add_executable()` or `add_library()` call.

As an example, if your project's sources are in `src`, and you need headers from `include`, you could do it like this:

```
include_directories(include)

add_executable(MyExec
  src/main.c
  src/other_source.c
  include/header1.h
  include/header2.h
)
```

Comment: Do you really need to add headers to `add_executable`?  I thought CMake figured out the include file dependencies automatically.

Comment: @ColinDBennett You don't have to list them for dependency reasons - CMake figures out build dependencies just fine if you don't. But if you list them, they are considered part of the project, and will be listed as such in IDEs (which was the topic of the question).

Comment: At least for QtCreator it is not necessary to add class.h in case a class.cpp exists. Only lonely.h needs to be added to source. See tutorial at [www.th-thielemann.de/cmake](http://www.th-thielemann.de/cmake)

Comment: If you've specified "include" as one of the include directories, why would you need to prefix the header files in your source-file list with "include/"?

Comment: @Oscar You mean in the CMakeList in `add_executable`? Because that's giving the paths to the files *to CMake*, not to the compiler. Source file arguments to `add_executable` are relative to the current source directory.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO Thanks for the reply. So you're saying include_directories is for the compiler, and is ignored by CMake? Is it really necessary to put header files in the add_executable list at all, then, as long as their parent dir is in include_directories?

Comment: @Oscar Answered in a comment above (in reply to Colin D Bennett)

Answer (score 60):

### Structure of project

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── external //We simulate that code is provided by an "external" library outside of src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── conversion.cpp
│   ├── conversion.hpp
│   └── README.md
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── evolution   //propagates the system in a time step
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── evolution.cpp
│   │   └── evolution.hpp
│   ├── initial    //produces the initial state
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── initial.cpp
│   │   └── initial.hpp
│   ├── io   //contains a function to print a row
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── io.cpp
│   │   └── io.hpp
│   ├── main.cpp      //the main function
│   └── parser   //parses the command-line input
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── parser.cpp
│       └── parser.hpp
└── tests  //contains two unit tests using the Catch2 library
    ├── catch.hpp
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── test.cpp
```

### How to do it

**1. The top-level CMakeLists.txt is very similar to Recipe 1, Code reuse with functions and macros**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)
  
project(recipe-07 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

# defines targets and sources
add_subdirectory(src)

# contains an "external" library we will link to
add_subdirectory(external)

# enable testing and define tests
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

**2.Targets and sources are defined in src/CMakeLists.txt (except the conversion target)**

```
add_executable(automata main.cpp)
  
add_subdirectory(evolution)
add_subdirectory(initial)
add_subdirectory(io)
add_subdirectory(parser)

target_link_libraries(automata
  PRIVATE
    conversion
    evolution
    initial
    io
    parser
  )
```

**3.The conversion library is defined in external/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(conversion "")

target_sources(conversion
  PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/conversion.cpp
  PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/conversion.hpp
  )

target_include_directories(conversion
  PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
  )
```

**4.The src/CMakeLists.txt file adds further subdirectories, which in turn contain CMakeLists.txt files. They are all similar in structure; src/evolution/CMakeLists.txt contains the following:**

```
add_library(evolution "")

target_sources(evolution
  PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/evolution.cpp
  PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/evolution.hpp
  )
target_include_directories(evolution
  PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
  )
```

**5.The unit tests are registered in tests/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable(cpp_test test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(cpp_test evolution)

add_test(
  NAME
    test_evolution
  COMMAND
    $<TARGET_FILE:cpp_test>
  )
```

### How to run it

```
$ mkdir -p build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ cmake --build .
```

Refer to: https://github.com/sun1211/cmake_with_add_subdirectory

Comment: The question didn't ask anything about unit tests or using third-party projects. To me those parts of this answer just seem like unnecessary noise. Sure, it could be useful in a question that asks for that info, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 39):

Add `include_directories("/your/path/here")`.

This will be similar to calling `gcc` with `-I/your/path/here/` option.

Make sure you put double quotes around the path. Other people didn't mention that and it made me stuck for 2 days. So this answer is for people who are very new to CMake and very confused.

Comment: except it randomly fails half the time. =/

Answer (score 30):

CMake is more like a script language if comparing it with other ways to create Makefile (e.g. make or qmake). It is not very cool like Python, but still.

There are no such thing like a "*proper way*" if looking in various opensource projects how people include directories. But there are two ways to do it.

1. Crude [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) will append a directory to the current project and all other descendant projects which you will append via a series of [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) commands. Sometimes people say that such approach is legacy.
2. A more elegant way is with [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html). It allows to append a directory for a specific project/target without (maybe) unnecessary inheritance or clashing of various include directories. Also allow to perform even a subtle configuration and append one of the following markers for this command.

**PRIVATE** - use only for this specified build target

**PUBLIC** - use it for specified target and for targets which links with this project

**INTERFACE** -- use it only for targets which links with the current project

PS:

1. Both commands allow to mark a directory as SYSTEM to give a hint that it is not your business that specified directories will contain warnings.
2. A similar answer is with other pairs of commands [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html)/[add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html),  [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html)/[CMAKE_C_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html?highlight=cmake_c_flags)

Comment: "will append a directory to the current project and all other descendant projects which you will append via a series of add_subdirectory" -- Unfortunately, _that is wrong_. The truth is that it applies to all targets in the _same_ (even those that came before the `include_directories` call) and to targets in `add_subdirectories` that came _after_ the call (_not before_)... and this is why we say it's legacy. **DO NOT USE `include_directories`, EVER**

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.

My project directory was like this:

```
    --project
    ---Classes
    ----Application
    -----.h and .c files
    ----OtherFolders
    --main.cpp
```

And what I used to include the files in all those folders:

```
    file(GLOB source_files CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
            "*.h"
            "*.cpp"
            "Classes/*/*.cpp"
            "Classes/*/*.h"
    )

    add_executable(Server ${source_files})
```

And it totally worked.

Comment: Remembering that cmake is a 'build system generator' and not a 'build system' using file glob is not a good idea in modern cmake (CMake with versions 3.0 and above) because file globs are evaluated at 'build' time and not 'build system generation' time. 
See link : https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1

Comment: Just add `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`.

Comment: In CMake the use of file GLOB should be avoided every time you can, when you use it in a large project you will have a boilerplate of includes at the end.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options.

The Old:

```
include_directories(${PATH_TO_DIRECTORY})
```

and the new

```
target_include_directories(executable-name PRIVATE ${PATH_TO_DIRECTORY})
```

To use `target_include_directories`, You need to have your executable defined - `add_executable(executable-name sourcefiles)`.

So your code should appear like

```
add_executable(executable-name sourcefiles)
target_include_directories(executable-name PRIVATE ${PATH_TO_DIRECTORY})
```

You can read more here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html

Comment: What case do you suggest the scope keyword, "PRIVATE"?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
set(SOURCE main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE})

# target_include_directories must be added AFTER add_executable
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${INTERNAL_INCLUDES})
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}`.
That's what was causing problems for me.

Example should be like this:

```
target_include_directories(projectname
    PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include"                          
)
```

PUBLIC for dependencies which you want to be included by a parent project.
PRIVATE for ones that you don't.

Answer (score 1):

In all the answers to this question, there is a whole lot of "how" (to get what you want), and precious little "why" (digging into the problem that motivated the question and what the asker may have misunderstood about the ways in which different types of tools like IDEs and build tools do / do not interact and share information with each other, and what information CMake passes / needs to pass to those tools).

This question is vexing, as it is motivated by a specific behaviour of a specific IDE- Code::Blocks) and CMake, but then poses a question unrelated to that IDE and instead about Makefiles and CMake, assuming that they have done something wrong with CMake which led to a problem with Makefiles, which led to a problem with their IDE.

TL;DR CMake and Makefiles have their own way of tracking header dependencies given include directories and source files. How CMake configures the Code::Blocks IDE is a completely separate story.

#### What is an "external" header in CMake? (no such thing)

> I realized recently that the issue seemed to be that CMake considered those header files to be external to the project. [...]
> It therefore seems to me that CMake consider those headers to be external to the project, and does not track them in the depends

As far as I know, there is no official or useful definition of "external header" when it comes to CMake. I have not seen that phrase used in documentation. Also note that the word "project" is a quite overloaded term. Each buildsystem generated by CMake consists of one top-level project, possibly including other external or subdirectory projects. Each project can contain multiple targets (libraries, executables, etc.). What CMake refers to as a target sometimes translates to what IDEs call projects (Ix. Visual Studio, and possibly Code::Blocks). If you had to given such a phrase a meaning, here's what would make sense to me:

In the case that the question is referring to some IDEs' sense of the word "project", which CMake calls "targets", header files are external to a project would be those that aren't intended to be accessed through any of the include directories of a target (Ex. Include directories that come from targets linked to the target in question).

In the case that the question is referring to CMake's sense of the word "project": Targets are either part of a project (defined/created by a call to the `project()` command, and built by the generated buildsystem), or `IMPORTED`, (not built by the generated buildsystem and expected to already exist, or built by some custom step added to the generated buildsystem, such as via `ExternalProject_Add`). Include directories of `IMPORTED` targets would be those headers which are external to the CMake project in question, and include directories of non-`IMPORTED` targets would be those that are "part of" the project.

#### Does CMake track header dependencies? (It depends!)

> [...] CMake consider those headers to be external to the project, and does not track them in the depends

I'm not super familiar with the history of CMake, or with header dependency tracking in build tooling, but here is what I've gathered from the searching I have done on the topic.

CMake itself doesn't have much to do with any information related to header/include dependencies of implmentation files / translation units. The only way in which that information is important to CMake is if CMake needs to be the one to tell the generated buildsystem what those dependencies are. It's the generated buildsystem which wants to track changes in header file dependencies to avoid any unnecessary recompilation. For the Unix Makefiles generator in particular, before CMake 3.20, CMake would do the job of scanning header/include dependencies to tell the Makefiles buildsystem about those dependencies. Since v3.20, where supported by the compiler, CMake delegates that responsibility to the compiler by default. See [the option which can be used to revert that behaviour here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_DEPENDS_USE_COMPILER.html).

The exact details of how header/include dependency scanning differs for each supported CMake generator. For example, you can find some high-level description about the Ninja capabilities/approach [on their manual](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#ref_headers). Since this question is only about Makefiles, I won't attempt to go into detail about other generators.

Notice how to get the header/include dependency information for the *buildsystem*, you only need to give CMake a list of a target's include directories, and a list of the implementation source files to compile? You don't need to give it a list of header files because that information can be scanned for (either by CMake or by a compiler).

#### Do IDEs get information about target headers by scanning? (they *could*)

Each IDE can display information in whatever way it wants. Problems like you are having with the IDE not showing headers usually only happen for IDE display formats of the project layout other than the filesystem layout (project headers files are usually in the same project directory as implementation files). For example, such non-filesystem layout views are available in Visual Studio and Code::Blocks.

Each IDE can get header information in whatever way it chooses. As far as I am aware (but I may be wrong for Visual Studio), both Visual Studio and Code::Blocks expect the list of project headers to be explicitly listed in the IDE project configuration files. There are other possible approaches (Ex. header dependency scanning), but it seems that many IDEs choose the explicit list approach. My guess would be because it is simple implementation-wise.

Why would scanning be burdensome for an IDE to find header files associated with a target?(Note: this is somewhat speculation, since I am not a maintainer of any such tools and have only used a couple of them) An IDE could implement the file scanning (which itself is a complicated task), but to know which headers are "in" the target, they'd either need to get information from the buildsystem about how the translation units of the target will get compiled, and that's assuming that all "not-in-target" header include paths are specified with a "system"-like flag, which doesn't have to be the case. Or, it could try to get that information from the meta-buildsystem, which here is CMake. Or it could try to do what CMake now does and try to invoke the selected compiler to scan dependencies. But in either case, they'd have to make some difficult decision about which buildsystems, meta buildsystems, and/or compilers to support, and then do the difficult work of extracting that information from whatever formats those tools store that information in, possibly without any guarantees that those formats will be the same in future tool versions (supporting a change in the format in a newer tool version could be similar to having to supporting a completely separate tool). The IDE could do all that work, or it could just ask you to give it a list of the headers belonging to each target. As you can see, there are cons to the diversity in tooling that the C/C++ ecosystem has. There are pros too, but that's outside the scope of this question.

On the bright side, CMake actually does have a mechanism to try to take some of that work off your shoulders. For such IDEs that have non-filesystem-views, it does implement a simple-heuristic to try to find header files that are associated with source files...

#### How does header file discovery work for the Code::Blocks IDE generator for CMake?

> At least, when generating a Code::Blocks project the header files do not appear within the project (the source files do).

Here's something interesting: The Code::Blocks editor has the concept of source files and header files that are part of a project, and since CMake doesn't *expect/require* its users to tell it about each and every header file in the project (it only needs to know about what include directories should be associated with targets), it tries to use a certain heuristic to discover header files that are associated to implementation files. That heuristic is very basic: take the path of each source file in a project, and try changing the extenstion to be like one that is usually given to header files, and see if any such file exists. See the `cmExtraCodeBlocksGenerator::CreateNewProjectFile` member function in `:/Source/cmExtraCodeBlocksGenerator.cxx`.

In ["Pitchfork Layout"](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?force=1&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork/develop/data/spec.bs#tld.src) terminology, it would be said that the heuristic assumes that the project uses "merged-header" placement instead of "split-header" placement, where there are separate `src/` and `include/` directories. So if you don't use merged-header layout, or otherwise have any target headers that don't meet that heuristic, such as utility header files, you'll need to explicitly tell CMake about those files (Ex. using [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html)) for it to pass that knowledge on to the IDE config it generates.

Further readings:

- [Here's the CMake documentation on its Code::Blocks generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/CodeBlocks.html) (not much info related to the topic at hand, but good to link anyway).
- [Here's Code::Blocks' documentation on its "Project View"](https://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html#x3-40001.1). [Here's the `.cpb` xml schema documentation](https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Project_file) (see in particular, the `Unit` element).
- If you want to read the CMake code which does the associated header detection, you can find it in [the `cmExtraCodeBlocksGenerator::CreateNewProjectFile` function in the Source/cmExtraCodeBlocksGenerator.cxx file](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmExtraCodeBlocksGenerator.cxx).

#### Closing Words

I'm certain there are many people who know these tools better than I do. If you are one of those people and notice that I have made a mistake, please graciously correct me in the comments or in chat, or just to edit this post.

Note that while installation of build artifacts is an important part of many projects' lifecycles and is therefore incorporated into the designs of most C/C++ buildsystems, since the question didn't explicitly ask about the configuring the installation part, I have chosen to leave it out of this answer, since it in itself is not a trivial topic to cover (just see how long the related chapters in the "Mastering CMake" book are: [The chapter on installation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Install.html), and [the chapter on importing and exporting](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/cmake/Help/guide/importing-exporting/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

In newer CMake versions we can limit our include-paths to target, like:

```
target_include_directories(MyApp PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myFolder")
```

I mean, if the `CMakeLists.txt` has multiple targets, else, the include-paths are NOT shared with other `CMakeLists.txt` scripts, and it's enough to do something like:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myFolder")
```

However, maybe we can simulate what `target_include_directories(...)` does for CMake 2.8.10 or older versions, like:

```
set_property(
    TARGET MyApp
    APPEND PROPERTY
        INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myFolder"
)
```

All done, **but seems** if you want source-files to be re-compiled once any header-file they use is changed, all such header-files need to be added to each target as well, like:

```
set(SOURCES src/main.cpp)

set(HEADERS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myFolder/myHeaderFile.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myFolder/myOtherHeader.h
)

add_executable(MyApp ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```

> Where with "seems" I mean that, CMake could detect such header-files automatically if it wanted, because it parses project's C/C++ files anyway.