# How to add all headers using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

for a c++ project, I can use

`aux_source_directory` to add all the cpp files; however this command does not include header files; anyway to add header files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly add include directories with CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `file` command to add all the files that you want, like

```
file(GLOB SOURCES
    your-folder/*.hxx
    your-folder/*.cxx
)
add_executable(yourProj ${SOURCES})
```