# Dirty generated header doesn't rebuild dependant target

Tags: cmake

I've a target which has some headers in its `SOURCES` among others; these are generated using [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/command/add_custom_command.html).  Here's the excerpt

```
set(MY_SOURCES
  a.txt
  b.txt)

set(MY_HEADERS)
foreach (TXT ${MY_SOURCES})
  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${TXT}.h
    COMMAND txt2h
    -i "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${TXT}"
    -o "${TXT}.h"
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${TXT}
    COMMENT "Generating header from ${TXT}"
    VERBATIM)
  list(APPEND MY_HEADERS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TXT}.h")
endforeach ()

add_executable(exe main.cpp ${MY_HEADERS})
target_include_directories(exe PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

This generates (`cmake -B build`) and builds (`cmake --build build`) fine.

When I edit `a.txt` and run `cmake --build build`.  It regenerates `a.txt.h` since I see

> Generating header from a.txt

However, the `exe` target isn't built.  Since the generated header is listed as a source for `exe`, I'm hoping it should also make `exe` dirty and rebuild it.  What am I missing?

I verified the timestamps on `a.txt` and `a.txt.h` match and are newer than the `exe`'s.

## References

1. [Adding a custom command and generated file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20a%20Custom%20Command%20and%20Generated%20File.html) (Official CMake tutorial)
2. [Generated sources in CMake builds](https://crascit.com/2017/04/18/generated-sources-in-cmake-builds/)

Comment: Not sure it helps but [Handling header files dependencies with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461000/handling-header-files-dependencies-with-cmake) has some good answers. Every answer has something interesting to say regarding this.

Comment: And `add_executable(exe main.cpp ${MY_HEADERS})` looks wrong anyway. That will treat the headers as implementation files if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I've usually seen headers listed in `add_executable`. This makes sure the executable is rebuilt when a header changes, no? Also IDEs list the headers if put there; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174499/why-add-header-files-into-add-library-add-executable-command-in-cmake

Comment: I see. Ok, that's probably the proper way to do it then. I wonder if adding the [`HEADER_FILE_ONLY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/HEADER_FILE_ONLY.html#prop_sf:HEADER_FILE_ONLY) property would make a difference?

Comment: `However, the exe target isn't built.` In what way does "exe target" depend on the header? Does `main.cpp` include it? I.e. _what exactly_ should be rebuild and in what way when `"${TXT}.h"` changes?

Comment: @KamilCuk Shouldn't `exe` be rebuilt if `main.cpp` or any of `${MY_HEADERS}` are updated (because of `add_executable(exe main.cpp ${MY_HEADERS})`)?

Comment: No, it should not. Executables depend on object files, object files depend on cpp files. No cpp files change -> no object files change -> no need to rebuild executable. Unless the cpp file includes the header, in which case it depends on it. Adding header files to `add_executable` only makes them show in some ide.

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh, thanks. That may very well be the problem then.

Comment: @Kamil That indeed was the issue. Today I learned that CMake scans every C or C++ source for included headers (and the headers they include in turn) to form the dependency tree.  I'm dealing with txt files which are processed differently, so I've to build this tree manually.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kamil I'd be happy to accept your answer, if you give one.

Comment: @KamilCuk Mind writing someting up about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header files are not compiled. Executable depends on object files, which are produced from `cpp` files. Only when one of `cpp` files include the header, then it needs to be recompiled when the header changes, then the executable will be recompiled when the header changes.

Adding the header to `add_executable` only makes it show in some IDEs, it has no effect.

Comment: Crystal clear! Thanks!