# Attach library .h to makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake

I would like to add library wiringPi.h to my Makefile in cmake, but cmake doesn't see this header.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( program )
include_directories(include)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( program program.cpp )
target_link_libraries( program ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

The project organization is:

|-- CMakeLists.txt
|
|-- program.cpp
|
|-- wiringPi.h

How should I add this header to Makefile?

Comment: You don't need to add headers. CMake figures them out by itself.

Comment: @Stargateur I dumped add_executable( program program.cpp ) and I try your way and it doesn't work

/home/luko/naukacop/program.cpp:2:22: fatal error: wiringPi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/program.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/program.dir/program.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/program.dir/program.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/program.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/program.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( program )
include_directories(wiringPi)
add_executable(wiringPi
  lukasz22/naukacop/wiringPi.h
)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( program program.cpp wiringPi.h)
target_link_libraries( program ${OpenCV_LIBS} ) 
`
@Stargateur Is it correct? I get some errors :(

Comment: @Stargateur Sorry, today I started using Stackoverflow.
`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    luko/naukacop/wiringPi.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
'

Comment: Yes, I used tree, but my library is in folder, but I see my library only in CMakeFiles

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for your time and help

[here](http://iv.pl/images/06202576525838325994.jpg)
-> That's the tree

Answer (score 0):

This must work in your case:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(program)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(program program.cpp wiringPi.h)
target_link_libraries(program ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

If you need more information read this [How to properly add include directories with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake). You should read the official [tuto](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/). Be aware that 2.8 is a very old version, you should update to the latest stable.