# FlyCapture2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to read images from a ptgrey camera on Ubuntu with OpenCV. I have installed the SDK and the SDK samples work.
I am unable to run the samples from ptgrey regarding the image conversion. I have the cpp files but I get the above error when I run the make file.
What should I add to my CMakeLists.txt to detect the FlyCapture2.h file?

Comment: What do you have now? How do you check for the header file now? And are the files on a case-sensitive filesystem and you use the wrong upper-/lower-casing?

Comment: where's FlyCapture2.h on your hard drive?

Comment: FlyCapture.h is in the /usr/include/flycapture folder. 
I do not know what to add to the CMakeLists.txt to make it work. There isn't info on the documentary either.

Comment: what's the #include line in the code file? is it `#include "flycapture/FlyCapture2.h"` or `#include "FlyCapture2.h"`?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake and add `/usr/include/flycapture` as additional include directory. You don't need to add the headers to the list of source files, just add the directory to the include directories.