# CMAKE: target_include_directories and include_directories

Tags: cmake

I'm reading the cmakelist file of a big project, and confused about the usage of `target_include_directories` and `include_directories`.

The `include_directories` should be able to add all header files to path where the compiler search for. But I still see some `target_include_directories` in the cmakelist file of sub directories, that specify some include path for a specific target.

Can anybody explain the usage of these two? As far as I concerned, add all paths of header file to `include_directories` should be enough.

Comment: The `include_directories` command could be used to add global directories that are needed by all (or at least multiple) targets. The `target_include_directories` command could be used to add single paths just needed by the specific target.

Comment: Here is one example of "target_include_directories" from the user, Jasper's question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/71691881/5595995.

Comment: Example of different syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73810182/5595995

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`include_directories` applies to all the targets in a particular CMakeLists.txt file. For example, let's say you have

```
include_directories( ../include
   ${SOME_OTHER_PATH}/include
)

add_library(math ${MATH_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(math 
    math_include
)

add_executable(calculator ${MYCALCULATOR_SOURCES})   

target_include_directories(calculator 
    calc_include
)
```

`calculator` is an executable target and `math` is a library target defined in the same CMakeLists.txt. The folders `../include` and `${SOME_OTHER_PATH}/include` are visible to both. That means cmake will add the option `-I../include -I<expanded-some-other-path>/include` to both these targets when their sources are compiled.

For `target_include_directories`, the include path `calc_include` applies only to the `calculator` target and `math_include` applies only to the `math` target. As specified, `math_include` and `calc_include` would be (usually) subfolders present in the same folder that contains the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Shouldn't we a keyword for scope like `target_include_directories( calculator PUBLIC cal_include )`? from https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html I faced an error at CMake version 3.25.2 without the keyword for scope.