# Getting several CMake errors

Tags: c, cmake

I am new to CMake and was experimenting with it. Here is folder structure:
[Structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2FrG.png)

I have `CMakeLists.txt` in every folder. 
The main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0076 NEW)

project(game_of_life)

add_subdirectory(console)

add_subdirectory(game)

# add_subdirectory(sdl)

set (SRC main.c)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "")
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SRC})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC console game)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

And every other CMakeLists.txt s are similar to each other:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0076 NEW)

project(console_ame_of_life)

SET(VALUE CACHE STRING "console_value")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} board_drawer.h)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC board_drawer.c board_drawer.h)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE m)

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC USING_LIB=$VALUE)


install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME})
install(FILES game.h DESTINATION include)
```

When I run `make` command on `build` folder ,it produces following errors

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconsole
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgame
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/game_of_life.dir/build.make:84: game_of_life] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:117: CMakeFiles/game_of_life.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I have include them in `main.c` like this:

```
#include "game/game.h"
#include "console/board_drawer.h"
```

I have searched for these errors but couldn't find appropriate answer. Can you please explain what these errors mean and what causes them. 
**Thank you for your time**

Comment: There are many questions with this type of CMake error on Stack Overflow already, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57671273/3987854) one. Almost *all* of them have the same issue, and resolution. You must **define** the target being used in the `target_*` commands, via a call to `add_library()` or `add_executable()`. In addition, each of your sub-directories should use a **different** name for `project_name()`.

Comment: I added `add_executable()` before `target_link_libraries()` in my main CMakeLists.txt file. In others there are not any `add_executable()`  and I do not know what should I define before `target_sources()` to overcome the problem

Comment: Like I said, you can use `add_library()` or `add_executable()` to define a new target. It looks like each of the CMake files in your subdirectories is missing these calls, perhaps you want `add_library()` in each of these. There are examples of how to do this, such as [this example](https://cmake.org/examples/) from the CMake site.

Comment: That solved the issue ,thanks. But now the libraries that i added in `add_library()` raise this error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconsole` `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgame`

Comment: The libraries linked with `target_link_libraries()` must be *target* names, or valid library names. Do the target names linked here (`console`, `game`, etc) match the *target* names you created in each sub-directory (e.g. `add_library(console ...)`)?

Comment: I have added updated version.I think that the names match but you can see for yourself. Thank you for your time

Comment: "I think that the names match but you can see for yourself." - I see you link with `console` but the name of the project is `console_ame_of_life`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`target_sources()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) command (along with *all* of the `target_*` commands) must specify an **existing** CMake target as the first argument. CMake targets are generated by calls to `add_library()` or `add_executable()`.

Also note, the [`${PROJECT_NAME}`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_NAME.html) variable contains the name given to the most recently called `project()` command. So, your code:

```
project(console_ame_of_life)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} board_drawer.h)
```

will create a CMake library target named `console_ame_of_life`.

Subsequently, in calls to `target_link_libraries()`, you can use CMake target names, or names of actual libraries on your system. Because the targets `console` and `game` have **not** been defined, CMake instead tries to find libraries on your system called `console` and `game`. This leads to your error message.

To fix this, just make sure the target names match. You can change the target name from `console_ame_of_life` to `console`, for example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0076 NEW)

project(console_ame_of_life)

SET(VALUE CACHE STRING "console_value")

# Here, you should specify the library type (e.g. STATIC or SHARED).
add_library(console SHARED)

target_sources(console PUBLIC board_drawer.c board_drawer.h)

target_include_directories(console PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(console INTERFACE m)

target_compile_definitions(console PUBLIC USING_LIB=$VALUE)


install(TARGETS console)
install(FILES game.h DESTINATION include)
```