# C++ Packing and Distrubuting

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

How can I install runtime dependencies with cmake `INSTALL()` commad.

I want to install `${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}` headers and `${OpenCV_LIBS}` libraries with cmake `INSTALL()` functionality.

Comment: Headers aren't runtime dependencies. It's not quite clear what you want to do. Did you mean *build* dependencies instead? Are you building OpenCV or do you want to use OpenCV in your project?

Comment: I builded OpenCV from source to use in my project and builded in with no error. I can run my app from build folder without error.  When i use cmake INSTALL command, my app istalling properly but i cannot run my app from install directory. It returns  `Cannot find shared library` or `cannot find shared object`. How can I overcome to this problem, I want to distribute all runtime dependencies with my package, or if you can suggest a better approach?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218752/18667225 ?

Comment: I tried this with target_include_directories. İs there any main difference between include_directories() and target_include_directories() ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51968659/18667225