# CMake->CodeLite: Can I tell CMake to include header files in the CodeLite workspace?

Tags: c++, cmake, codelite

I'm using CMake for a C++ project. When I create a CodeLite workspace with `cmake -G "CodeLite - Unix Makefiles"`, I have to manually add header files into the workspace - I guess, because they aren't listed in any `CMakeLists.txt`.

Is there a way to configure the generation of the CodeLite project in a way that header files (and other `#include`d files, such as template definitions) are also included?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703725/11770674) it seems like I'd have to include all header files in the appropriate `CMakeLists.txt`. I'd vastly prefer it if I don't have to do that. Is that possible?

Comment: "I'd vastly prefer it if I don't have to do that." - What **exactly** you want to avoid? Typing all header manually? - You may always use `file(GLOB)` for collect all headers in a directory.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid putting in all header files manually. Using file(GLOB) is discouraged by the CMake documentation, so I'd rather avoid that as well.
The point is, that ```make``` knows which header files are required, without putting them into a CMakeLists.txt. So that information is available *somewhere*.

Comment: "The point is, that `make` knows which header files are required" - list of required headers is collected only during the **build** (and is updated every further build). So this list cannot be used by IDE which sees only the *configured* project. What IDE can is collecting **all header files** from some **include directories**. Which is mostly usable feature.