# Files in the same folder all include files in the same folder but with folder name infront

Tags: c++, git

I cloned a repo from github using git bash, I specifically cloned the "C++ requests" library. But when the folder is cloned into my working directory, with the name "cReq", and I include files from one of the folders in the "cReq" folder that file includes files that are in same folder as itself but with folder name infront.

If you dont understand what I am talking about check out: https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr/tree/master/include/cpr, and see how every files includes from files in the same folder but with the "cpr/" in front in the include tags. Have I misunderstood something or is there a way to change this without having to go into every file. Sorry if this sounds a little tedious, it is pretty hard to explain.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably just need to set an include directory for your compiler.  Did you read the documentation for your compiler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake

Comment: How do set a include directory in my compiler, I have tried searching around but I can't seem to find a good answer

Comment: add ` -I/path/to/your/include/directory ` to your compilation syntax