# CMake can't find header file

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project that looks like this.

```
.
├──include
|  └──utilities.hpp
├──source
|  ├──main.cpp
|  └──utilities.cpp
└──CMakeLists.txt
```

Where both `source/main.cpp` and `source/utilities.cpp` have an `#include "include/utilities.hpp` directive, and the contents of `CMakeLists.txt`are:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
project(search VERSION 1.0.0)


add_executable(
    search
    source/utilities.cpp
    source/main.cpp
    include/utilities.hpp
)
include_directories(search PUBLIC include)
```

When I run `make VERBOSE+1`, I get the following output:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/search.dir/source/utilities.cpp.o
/home/mohammed/Work/Projects/search/source/utilities.cpp:1:10: fatal error: include/utilities.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "include/utilities.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/search.dir/build.make:63 : CMakeFiles/search.dir/source/utilities.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76 : CMakeFiles/search.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84 : all] Error 2
```

I tried all the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake). But none of them worked.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

p.s If it is not yet clear, I am new to CMake.

Comment: In CMake, `add_executable` only needs the `.cpp` files. You've added     `include/utilities.hpp`. This causes confusion between the compiler and CMake where to find that file. (Not an answer, since the quoted error message is caused by an earlier problem compiling utilities.cpp)

Answer (score 3):

[`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) != [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories).  Looks like you meant to use the latter.

Additionally, as RoQuOTriX pointed out: When you add a directory to the include path, includes should be relative to that directory.  So if `include` is on your include path, you would want to `#include "utilities.hpp"` instead of `#include "include/utilities.hpp"`.

Comment: I tried both `include_directories(include)` and `target_include_directories(searchPUBLIC include)` with similar results.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify `include_directories()` directly you don't need to use the relative paths in your source files:

```
#include "include/utilities.hpp"
```

Instead use:

```
#include "utilities.hpp"
```

If you instead want to keep the relative paths then you need to remove the `include_directories()` from the `CMakeLists.txt`.

The `include_directories()` tells the compiler where it should search for includes.

Comment: That actually worked. I don't know how I managed to miss the fact that the verbose message was saying `-I ./include` rather than `-I .` Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the contents of CMakeLists.txt to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
project(search VERSION 1.0.0)
set(WORKING_DIRECTORY /home/mohammed/Work/Projects/search)

add_executable(
    search
    ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/source/utilities.cpp
    ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/source/main.cpp
    ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/include/utilities.hpp
)

include_directories(${WORKING_DIRECTORY})
```

A huge thanks to [RoQuOTrix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8473031/roquotrix).

Comment: It is not necessary to add .hpp files to your `add_executable` statement, and you should _really_ use `target_include_directories` over `include_directories` (in addition to removing `include/` from your `#include` statement.