# how to set AntTweakBar in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Trying to run this source code I found my self forced to use AntTweakBar library for rotations but every effort I made to set cmake to find it has failed I couldn't include it like the other libraries I appreciate any help in this regard you can present

main.cpp:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/euler_angles.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/norm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

// Include AntTweakBar
#include <AntTweakBar.h>


#include "common/shader.hpp"
#include "common/texture.hpp"
#include "common/controls.hpp"
#include "common/objloader.hpp"
#include "common/vboindexer.hpp"
#include "common/quaternion_utils.hpp" // See quaternion_utils.cpp for RotationBetweenVectors, LookAt and RotateTowards

vec3 gPosition1(-1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vec3 gOrientation1;

vec3 gPosition2( 1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
quat gOrientation2;

bool gLookAtOther = true;


int main( void )
{

    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 17 - Rotations", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize the GUI
    TwInit(TW_OPENGL_CORE, NULL);
    TwWindowSize(1024, 768);
    TwBar * EulerGUI = TwNewBar("Euler settings");
    TwBar * QuaternionGUI = TwNewBar("Quaternion settings");
    TwSetParam(EulerGUI, NULL, "refresh", TW_PARAM_CSTRING, 1, "0.1");
    TwSetParam(QuaternionGUI, NULL, "position", TW_PARAM_CSTRING, 1, "808 16");

    TwAddVarRW(EulerGUI, "Euler X", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &gOrientation1.x, "step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(EulerGUI, "Euler Y", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &gOrientation1.y, "step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(EulerGUI, "Euler Z", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &gOrientation1.z, "step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(EulerGUI, "Pos X"  , TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &gPosition1.x, "step=0.1");
    TwAddVarRW(EulerGUI, "Pos Y"  , TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &gPosition1.y, "step=0.1");
    TwAddVarRW(EulerGUI, "Pos Z"  , TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &gPosition1.z, "step=0.1");

    TwAddVarRW(QuaternionGUI, "Quaternion", TW_TYPE_QUAT4F, &gOrientation2, "showval=true open=true ");
    TwAddVarRW(QuaternionGUI, "Use LookAt", TW_TYPE_BOOL8 , &gLookAtOther, "help='Look at the other monkey ?'");

    // Set GLFW event callbacks. I removed glfwSetWindowSizeCallback for conciseness
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, (GLFWmousebuttonfun)TwEventMouseButtonGLFW); // - Directly redirect GLFW mouse button events to AntTweakBar
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, (GLFWcursorposfun)TwEventMousePosGLFW);          // - Directly redirect GLFW mouse position events to AntTweakBar
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, (GLFWscrollfun)TwEventMouseWheelGLFW);    // - Directly redirect GLFW mouse wheel events to AntTweakBar
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (GLFWkeyfun)TwEventKeyGLFW);                         // - Directly redirect GLFW key events to AntTweakBar
    glfwSetCharCallback(window, (GLFWcharfun)TwEventCharGLFW);                      // - Directly redirect GLFW char events to AntTweakBar


    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    // Hide the mouse and enable unlimited mouvement
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // Set the mouse at the center of the screen
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSetCursorPos(window, 1024/2, 768/2);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    // Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "StandardShading.vertexshader", "StandardShading.fragmentshader" );

    // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    GLuint ViewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "V");
    GLuint ModelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "M");

    // Get a handle for our buffers
    GLuint vertexPosition_modelspaceID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexPosition_modelspace");
    GLuint vertexUVID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexUV");
    GLuint vertexNormal_modelspaceID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexNormal_modelspace");

    // Load the texture
    GLuint Texture = loadDDS("uvmap.DDS");

    // Get a handle for our "myTextureSampler" uniform
    GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");

    // Read our .obj file
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
    bool res = loadOBJ("suzanne.obj", vertices, uvs, normals);

    std::vector<unsigned short> indices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> indexed_vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> indexed_uvs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> indexed_normals;
    indexVBO(vertices, uvs, normals, indices, indexed_vertices, indexed_uvs, indexed_normals);

    // Load it into a VBO

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &indexed_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint uvbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &indexed_uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint normalbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &indexed_normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate a buffer for the indices as well
    GLuint elementbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned short), &indices[0] , GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Get a handle for our "LightPosition" uniform
    glUseProgram(programID);
    GLuint LightID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "LightPosition_worldspace");

    // For speed computation
    double lastTime = glfwGetTime();
    double lastFrameTime = lastTime;
    int nbFrames = 0;

    do{

        // Measure speed
        double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
        float deltaTime = (float)(currentTime - lastFrameTime);
        lastFrameTime = currentTime;
        nbFrames++;
        if ( currentTime - lastTime >= 1.0 ){ // If last prinf() was more than 1sec ago
            // printf and reset
            printf("%f ms/frame\n", 1000.0/double(nbFrames));
            nbFrames = 0;
            lastTime += 1.0;
        }

        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programID);

        glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
                glm::vec3( 0, 0, 7 ), // Camera is here
                glm::vec3( 0, 0, 0 ), // and looks here
                glm::vec3( 0, 1, 0 )  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
                );

        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
        // Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to use Texture Unit 0
        glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                vertexPosition_modelspaceID,  // The attribute we want to configure
                3,                            // size
                GL_FLOAT,                     // type
                GL_FALSE,                     // normalized?
                0,                            // stride
                (void*)0                      // array buffer offset
                );

        // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                vertexUVID,                   // The attribute we want to configure
                2,                            // size : U+V => 2
                GL_FLOAT,                     // type
                GL_FALSE,                     // normalized?
                0,                            // stride
                (void*)0                      // array buffer offset
                );

        // 3rd attribute buffer : normals
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                vertexNormal_modelspaceID,    // The attribute we want to configure
                3,                            // size
                GL_FLOAT,                     // type
                GL_FALSE,                     // normalized?
                0,                            // stride
                (void*)0                      // array buffer offset
                );

        // Index buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);

        glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(4,4,4);
        glUniform3f(LightID, lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);

        { // Euler

            // As an example, rotate arount the vertical axis at 180�/sec
            gOrientation1.y += 3.14159f/2.0f * deltaTime;

            // Build the model matrix
            glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = eulerAngleYXZ(gOrientation1.y, gOrientation1.x, gOrientation1.z);
            glm::mat4 TranslationMatrix = translate(mat4(), gPosition1); // A bit to the left
            glm::mat4 ScalingMatrix = scale(mat4(), vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
            glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix * ScalingMatrix;

            glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

            // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader,
            // in the "MVP" uniform
            glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);



            // Draw the triangles !
            glDrawElements(
                    GL_TRIANGLES,      // mode
                    indices.size(),    // count
                    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,   // type
                    (void*)0           // element array buffer offset
                    );

        }
        { // Quaternion

            // It the box is checked...
            if (gLookAtOther){
                vec3 desiredDir = gPosition1-gPosition2;
                vec3 desiredUp = vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // +Y

                // Compute the desired orientation
                quat targetOrientation = normalize(LookAt(desiredDir, desiredUp));

                // And interpolate
                gOrientation2 = RotateTowards(gOrientation2, targetOrientation, 1.0f*deltaTime);
            }

            glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = mat4_cast(gOrientation2);
            glm::mat4 TranslationMatrix = translate(mat4(), gPosition2); // A bit to the right
            glm::mat4 ScalingMatrix = scale(mat4(), vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
            glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix * ScalingMatrix;

            glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

            // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader,
            // in the "MVP" uniform
            glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);


            // Draw the triangles !
            glDrawElements(
                    GL_TRIANGLES,      // mode
                    indices.size(),    // count
                    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,   // type
                    (void*)0           // element array buffer offset
                    );
        }

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

        // Draw GUI
        TwDraw();

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    // Cleanup VBO and shader
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &Texture);

    // Close GUI and OpenGL window, and terminate GLFW
    TwTerminate();
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(graphics)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(graphics main.cpp common/shader.hpp common/shader.cpp common/shader.hpp)
file(GLOB common CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "*.hpp" "*.cpp")

find_package(glfw3 3.3.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW 2.2.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
link_directories("/opt/homebrew/Cellar/anttweakbar/1.16/include")
set(ENV{DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH} [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/anttweakbar/1.16/lib/libAntTweakBar.dylib])

target_include_directories(graphics PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(graphics "-framework Cocoa")
target_link_libraries(graphics "-framework OpenGL")
target_link_libraries(graphics "-framework IOKit")
target_link_libraries(graphics glfw ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(graphics GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(graphics ${GLM_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(graphics ${AntTweakBar_LIBRARIES})
```

also I'm using mac m1 and downloaded AntTweakBar from homebrew

**edited**

so I followed the link suggested in the comments and it still doesn't find the antTweakBar

build:

```
====================[ Build | graphics | Debug ]================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/clonerplus/Desktop/graphics/cmake-build-debug --target graphics -- -j 6
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/clonerplus/Desktop/graphics/cmake-build-debug
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable graphics
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_TwAddVarRW", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwDraw", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwEventCharGLFW", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwEventKeyGLFW", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwEventMouseButtonGLFW", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwMouseMotion", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwMouseWheel", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwNewBar", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwSetParam", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TwWindowSize", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "RotateTowards(glm::qua<float, (glm::qualifier)0>, glm::qua<float, (glm::qualifier)0>, float)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "LookAt(glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "loadDDS(char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "loadOBJ(char const*, std::__1::vector<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&, std::__1::vector<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&, std::__1::vector<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "indexVBO(std::__1::vector<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&, std::__1::vector<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&, std::__1::vector<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&, std::__1::vector<unsigned short, std::__1::allocator<unsigned short> >&, std::__1::vector<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&, std::__1::vector<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&, std::__1::vector<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::__1::allocator<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [graphics] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/graphics.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/graphics.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [graphics] Error 2
```

Comment: Just follow the [guide](http://anttweakbar.sourceforge.net/doc/tools:anttweakbar:download) shipped with their project: "add the AntTweakBar `include` directory to your project include paths", "add the AntTweakBar `lib` directory to your project library paths", and "link with ... `AntTweakBar` if you are using Linux or OSX.". CMake has well-known expressions for every step among those.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you but after changing my cmake file it seems the configuration is still missing something

Comment: Please, post (add to the question post) the **exact error message** you got with your code.

Comment: You didn't link with `AntTweakBar` library. In CMake linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` call. Directories for search libraries could be added with `link_directories` (or `target_link_directories`) call. Setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in `CMakeLists.txt` neither links with the library nor adds search directories.

Comment: @Tsyvarev after changing it is it consequently I find my self as confused as someone lost in concepts of cmake and OpenGL at once without any pre-knowledge could you please provide me the exact form of finding and linking and if there is anything else that should be in cmake I didn't provided thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Stack Overflow already has the questions (and answers) about [adding include directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake) in CMake and [linking with libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library). Just read them and apply to your case.