# Include compiled library in c++ cmake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to implement fthe fineftp-server library into an cmake-project. I compiled fineftp-server and got my fineftp-serverd.lib-file. I tried to includ it with

```
link_directories(${3RDPARTY_DIR}/fineftp-server)
target_link_libraries(myproject_object_lib PUBLIC fineftp)
```

I get no error, but when I try to use or include the classes of the lib, they are not found. I am new to this, perhaps someone can give me a hint.

Comment: "when I try to use or include the classes of the lib, they are not found." - You need to be **more detailed**. What exactly have you tried (C++ code)? What exact error have you got? Your question should include [mcve].

Comment: Agreed, you didn't give us enough information to help understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know your concrete directory structure I can only give you a rather generic answer.

In your `CMakeLists.txt` file you need to use the `target_include_directories()` command. You can find the documentation of
this command here (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) also I can recommend you the **cmake-good
series** (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yFPO1ofyF0&list=PLK6MXr8gasrGmIiSuVQXpfFuE1uPT615s), if you want to learn more about CMake.

Here is an example of what your `CMakeLists.txt` file should probably look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.0)

project(myproject)

add_library(
    myproject_object_lib
    //...
)

target_include_directories(myproject_object_lib PUBLIC ${3RDPARTY_DIR})
```

Here you can find a post on StackOverflow which explains how to include directories more in depth ([How to properly add include directories with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake?rq=1))