# What lib do I have to include in Makefile when using MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream?

Tags: c++, winapi, makefile, ms-media-foundation

I'm currently working on a AAC Decoder on Windows using Microsoft Media Foundation. I'm using the Source Reader and it's method  MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream. When I compile I get following error:
*undefined reference to `MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream@12'*

- This is how my Makefile looks like under LIBS:
  LIBS = -lpthread -lFLAC-8 -lFLAC++-6 -lOpenAl32 -lm -lcurl-4 -lole32 -lmfplat

What other libs do I need to include?

Compiler used: mingw32 gcc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) show clearly that you need to link to Mfreadwrite.lib

Comment: I've tried both:
1) -lmfreadwrite

and

2) -Mfreadwrite.lib

But no luck

Comment: Get this when I add "-mfreadwrite":
C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmfreadwrite
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status


And I get this when I add "-Mfreadwrite.lib":
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfreadwrite.lib'

Comment: So where is mfreadwrite.lib on your machine? I'm assuming you do have it on your machine

Comment: The location for the .dll is under Windows/system32. I'm not sure where the .lib is though.

Comment: did you install it? It's normally distributed as part of the platform SDK or as part of visual studio

Comment: I have both the SDK and Visual Studio installed.

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696274(v=vs.85).aspx) show that it's part of the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx)

Comment: Please search your machine for the lib if you have the SDK installed

Comment: Have a look here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ltnps0zcjocb88/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-27%20at%2012.31.58.png?dl=0

Comment: Great so have you tried linking to the relevant one?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341387/adding-a-directory-for-the-headers-in-a-makefile

Comment: Are you using vanilla MinGW or MinGW-w64? If the former, then try the latter. MinGW-w64 has far better support for APIs introduced after Windows 2000.