# Adding a directory as the headers in a Makefile to can find recursive header file

Tags: makefile, include, include-path

How can I add a directory for the header files in the Makefile to avoid the error *.h not found, my directory at:

```
/home/work/cdi_driver
```

But my project header include to many header file in other paths:

```
/home/work/cdi_driver/magnum/magnum/basemodules/std/bstd.h
/home/work/cdi_driver/callisto/include/cal_fpindicator.h
/home/work/cdi_driver/jhcommon/include/jh_types.h
...
```

and in "bstd.h" header file it also includes many header file in other paths in cdi_driver directory, as below:

```
/home/work/cdi_driver/magnum/magnum/basemodules/std/types/nucleus/bstd_defs.h
```

How to avoid this error while header file is including nested?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a directory for the headers in a Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341387/adding-a-directory-for-the-headers-in-a-makefile)

Comment: @I'L'I: in this case i must use all INCx to point to all folders contain my header i am using? is there a flag to set my module folder is /home/work/cdi_driver but it can find to any header inside this path?

Comment: Try using `-I/home/work/cdi_driver/**`.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work !

Comment: Maybe post your `Makefile`; it couldn't hurt.