# CodeBlocks header common folder

Tags: c, codeblocks, header-files

I have multiple projects which have the same header files over and over again, is it possible to create a common utils folder with all the headers and their source files?

[Project files with header files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2lMI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. First make a folder and insert all of your header file in that folder. then create a makefile and you can add that folder for  the headers in a Makefile. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341387/adding-a-directory-for-the-headers-in-a-makefile)

Other option can be to give path in include like

```
#include "../Headers/check.h"
#include "../Headers/stackstring.h"
```

Comment: will this work when I am doing normal debugging though?

Comment: it's giving me undefined references, do I need to specify the path in the compiler?

Comment: Solution: added files to project and they got linked perfectly